# Converting Mysql TIME data type to JS Date - Hibernate HQL?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, hibernate, datetime

I'm trying to convert a simple HQL query to a readable time format (HH:MM) and honestly I'm a bit at a loss here.

My table definition (mysql) is as follows

```
  CREATE TABLE `Concert` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Concert Id',
    `stage_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Stage Id',
    `concert_time` TIME NOT NULL COMMENT 'Concert Time (HH:MM)',  
    `band_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Band Id',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (stage_id) REFERENCES Stage (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (band_id) REFERENCES Band (id)  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Class Model:

```
public class Concert {

    private int id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Timestamp concertTime;
    private Stage stage; 
    private Band band;
```

DAO:

```
public List<Concert> getConcertsByStageId(int id){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query q = session.createQuery("Select c.id, c.concertTime from Concert c where c.stage.id= :id");
        q.setParameter("id", id);
        List<Concert> concertList = (List<Concert>)q.list();
        System.out.println("count: " + concertList.size());

        return concertList;     
    }
```

I'm getting string outputs via AJAX like '1508763630000' (that is if i use DATETIME instead of date, when using date I could not convert the output).
I wanted to convert that string to a JavaScript Date object, which can I would display in my view later.

I'm aware that one can use the TIME_FORMAT() function in mysql, but that doesn't seem to work in my HQL query. Is there a chance I could achieve this with JS? Or anything I need to add to my hibernate query??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across a similar issue, here's how I managed to solve it:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("Select c.id, TIME_FORMAT(c.concert_time, '%H:%i'), c.band_id, "
                + "b.name, b.band_type, b.set_length, b.encore, b.relevance from Concert c left join Band b on b.id = c.band_id "
                + "where c.stage_id = :id");

        query.setParameter("id", id);       
        List<Object[]> rows = query.list();
        List<Concert> concertList = new ArrayList<Concert>();
```

And then iterate over result rows to construct your objects:

```
for(Object[] row : rows){

}
```